# How to protect code confidentiality （product using Python and ruby）

Tags: python, ruby, amazon-web-services, docker

We developed an AI assisted work product using Python and ruby.
For data security reasons, the customer requires the code to be installed on his server.
What technical solutions can we use to ensure easy deployment and no leakage of our code, or use open source encryption system? Or use a service of AWS?

Comment: For python script you can use pyinstaller (https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/)

Comment: @FaizanAlHassan Incorrect - while that helps with deployment, that does not help protect code confidentiality whatsoever

Comment: This is a very odd question. Best way to protected your work: a license and a contract with your customer. Do you want to protect your trained model, your architecture or something else? Did you develop the product for a compeditor? Reverse engineering your code and AI model should be much more expensive than hiring someone to built from scratch.

Comment: That's what software license is for. You can not prevent reverse-engineering, but you can make it illegal for them to profit from it or use the software to damage your company.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the legal aspects, from a technical perspective, there is no way to prevent the user from reverse engineering your code with enough time, as ultimately it is running on **their server**.

If you have anything that shouldn't ever be leaked, put the logic behind a secured API, which the local application can call - that can use AWS API Gateway if you wish to do so.

If the code cannot be deployed inside an API, you can obfuscate the code using solutions found online but you will only make it *harder*, not *impossible*.

Comment: This is the correct answer. In the end, it is really simple: stealing your code is a crime. So, just don't do business with criminals, and you are all good.